# I have 2 links: one for my image and one for my title. Why are they both redirecting to the same place?

Tags: html, css

I need the title link to direct to a separate page.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
 <div class="img-container design" data-category="design">
                <h3 class="pro2">Angular JS Sales List <a class="pro1" href="https://github.com/Daniel1836/Angular-JS-Project">Git Hub</a> </h3>
               <img src="img/angular.png">
                <a class="img-overlay" href="/portfolio/index2.html"></a>
                    <div class="img-overlay-text">
```

I've tried many combinations of ordering the code, but the link on the bottom is the one that both links redirect to, as if it is spanning the entire image length.

Thanks

*Edit* 
Here is the relevant CSS. The code is not my own.

```
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
  height: auto; }
  .img-container img {
    border-radius: 10px; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .img-container {
      width: 100%; } }

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(229, 46, 45, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0; }
  .img-overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1; }

.img-overlay-text {
  position: inherit;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center; }
  .img-overlay-text h3 {
    margin: 0; }
  .img-overlay-text p {
    color: #fff; }
```

Comment: It's because it's on the overlay, so you are actually never clicking on the picture.

Comment: could it be that the `a.img-overlay` is styled to cover the `.img-container`?
could not really say without css

Comment: put it in a snippet if possible

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in cases like this, so that people don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

The second link should be like this:

```
<a class="img-overlay" href="/portfolio/index2.html">
 <img src="img/angular.png" />
</a>
```